# About Automated testing, huge number of steps and perfomance issues

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm getting (i suppose) perfomance issues when I launch my test set against my app (Functional Front-End testing). This includes approx 350 Features with no less than 4 Scenarios each, mainly scenarios outline. What happens is that I'm getting false negatives (or false positives), tests are failing when I launch ALL test set, they work fine when launching individually or just some Features, and each Scenario is isolated properly

The main problems looks like the webapp is not full loaded when the majority of tests fails, although I'm using waits for page to be loaded, waits for visibility/clickability of elements etc.

I'm looking over the net but solutions arent going farther than already said stuff. Has anyone some ideas, good habits to put here or anything could bring some light?

Thanks in advance